# Preserving columns with HTML::TextToHTML

Tags: html, css, perl

I have a Perl script that converts text to HTML using [`HTML::TextToHTML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TextToHTML)

Some of the original text has quasi-tables in that their alignment matters.

For example

```
Job no Description               Completed
15     Paving from NE 32 to 45th  11-01-17
```

Right now I am using this code

```
use HTML::TextToHTML;

my $conv = new HTML::TextToHTML();

if ( $HTML eq 'Y' ) { # convert entire body to HTML                                                                                  

    $body = $conv->process_chunk($body);
}
```

But with the code above the lines often lose the appropriate spacing on some email clients.

Is there a way in `HTML::TextToHTML` to preserve the width of rows and their alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't do much better than setting

```
make_tables => 1
```

in the constructor, and possibly setting

```
table_type => { ALIGN => 1, PGSQL => 0, BORDER => 0, DELIM => 0 }
```

which will split words that are separated by two or more spaces into the columns of a table

But you may well have to edit your original text file a little to get the best results. For instance your column headings will be `Job no Description` and `Completed` because there is only a single space after `Job no`

Comment: As far as I can tell this seems to be about the best answer one can hope working within the constraints of TextToHTML although the alignment still is not working quite right for me. I am off to explore Emaill::Template in order to try to create better looking html emails.

Comment: @gatorreina: [`Email::Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Template) is far less intelligent than `HTML::TextToHTML` and is mostly about actually sending the mail. I doubt if you will get a better solution than the latter for making a guess at HTML markup from random text. It is an impossible task unless your text is very well behaved.

Comment: How do emails such as an Itunes receipt do it then? Are they simply converting a text file to HTML?

Comment: @gatorreina: I don't know anything about *iTunes*, but if you're talking about receiving an emailed receipt from Apple then they will have software that creates the HTML form of the receipt. It certainly isn't a matter of creating a text file and pushing it through a translation algorithm.

Comment: If you have a reasonably limited range of possible tables then you could write some Perl to add more precise delimiters to the rows and then use the `DELIM` table type.

Comment: I think that may be where I need to end up. I need to figure out how I can create good looking html emails with information that is easy to read.

Comment: @gatorreina: The proper way would be to generate HTML instead of (or as well as) the plain text output. It's far better to get things right in the first place than adding a hack to fix it elsewhere. That is *two wrongs* not making a *right*!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160437/discussion-between-gatorreina-and-borodin).